# Why is it "ha riparato (masc) la lavastoviglie" but "non la ha riparata (fem)"

Tags: pronouns, gender, auxiliary-verb, agreement, past-participle

I'm doing an online course and I just saw these two sentences:

> Il tuo ragazzo ha riparato la lavastoviglie?

and

> No, non la ha riparata.

Why is the verb masculine in the first case and feminine in the second? Is it because one is a question and the other not, or because of the order of the words?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of discrepancy has always existed in italian; it is referred as "[Accordo del participio passato](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/accordo-participio-passato)" (Accordance of the past participle) and there is not a "fixed" rule, the rules are kind of "liquid".

This [article](https://www.mauriziopistone.it/testi/discussioni/gramm05_concordanza.html) explains better your case:

> Il tuo ragazzo ha riparato la lavastoviglie?

In this sentence the direct object (*lavastoviglie*) is postponed and the gender accordance between it and the past participle can be (and usually is) omitted; the article from La Crusca also states that this form is to be preferred.

> No, non la ha riparata.

In this sentence there is an unstressed pronoun ("*la*" in "*la ha*" or "*l'ha*") that exerts a kind of "attraction force" that requires concordance to the past participle.